# Is there a patch for vulnerability in recent Linux kernels that offers root rights

Tags: kernel, security, root

> An error in the handling of special netlink messages in the Linux
>   kernel can allow a user to surreptitiously gain root privileges.

To read the rest of the article, please click the following link: http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Vulnerability-in-recent-Linux-kernels-offers-root-rights-1810597.html

My question is: has a patch been issued for Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10?

Comment: Also here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121603&p=12537724#post12537724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121240&p=12536278#post12536278

In part:

> Linux is not Windows and in general patches are released much faster.
>
> You may wish to bookmark this page - http://www.ubuntu.com/usn
>
> In the future, it is worth searching that page for security bugs and
>   fixes